# Converting HTML to CSV in PHP

Tags: php, html, file-conversion

I'm trying to convert HTML to CSV in PHP.

This is the code I'm using.

```
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pkb.csv');

$html = str_get_html($file_to_get);

$fp = fopen($file_to_get, "w");
foreach($html->find('tr') as $element) // find tr element inside the table
{
    $td = array();
    foreach( $element->find('tr') as $row) // look for tr tag and it to the array if it exists.
    {
        $td [] = $row->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td);

    $td = array();
    foreach( $element->find('td') as $row) // look for td and put into array
    {
        $td [] = $row->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td);
    }
fclose($fp);
exit;
```

`$file_to_get` is the path of the HTML file.

Currently, the CSV file that is being produced, is actually the code I have written here (this php file) rather than the content of the HTML file.

Comment: if you use a html file str_get_html wrong function, then use: file_get_html
then you open the HTML file... with fopen but why?